# Formatting a String to a LocalDateTime

Tags: java, java-time, datetimeformatter

I know this has been asked before, but I still have an error after looking at all the solutions.

I'm trying to parse a String to a LocalDateTime using a DateTimeFormatter.

This is my code:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class MainAppointment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String description = "12/02/2024 13:45:00";
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime result = LocalDateTime.parse(description,parser);
    }
}
```

And the error I get is
`Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '12/02/2023 13:45:00' could not be parsed at index 0`

I've tried changing the DateTimeFormatter pattern to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` and I even tried using `.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` instead of the ofPattern. And I still get the same error.

What am I doing wrong? It seems to be ok (I read a lot of other questions and tried the solutions).

Comment: [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Your formatter requires `year-month-day`, string is in format `day/month/year`. The meaning of each symbol is explained in the docs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: Usage: Converting a string to a date-time object is called *parsing*. The opposite conversion is what is called *formatting*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matches for the parser are wrong, try this:

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class MainAppointment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String description = "12/02/2024 13:45:00";
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime result = LocalDateTime.parse(description,parser);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe the `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"` pattern is more appropriate (assuming for Mexico)

Answer (score -2):

Your question was understood as below.

Convert "-" to "/", which distinguishes year, month, and day, and format "parser" in the class format of "LocalDateTime"

Can't I just use replace?

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class MainAppointment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String description = "12/02/2024 13:45:00";
        description.replace("-", "/")
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime result = LocalDateTime.parse(description,parser);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many problems here - 1) you don't reassign description with the new value, 2) the places of the replacement and the target are switched (both are unnecessary anyway, just build correct pattern) and 3) even if those were correct the pattern still won't match.

Comment: description = description.replace("-", "/")

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. It does not work. First it does not compile. After adding the missing semicolon I get `DateTimeParseException: Text '12/02/2024 13:45:00' could not be parsed at index 0`. Also please edit your answer instead of just posting a correction in a comment. After applying it I still get the sane exception.